# How to make kde (3) panel transparent with console command?

Tags: linux, kde-plasma, dcop

Maybe using dcop or something?

Answer (score 0):

```
kwriteconfig --file kickerrc --group General --key Transparent --type bool true
dcop kicker kicker configure
```

The first command updates the config file and the second tells the panel (kicker) to reload the config.